# Symfony User only stays Authenticated for one Request

Tags: symfony, postman, symfony4

I'm developing a Symfony API to interact with a React App, but I'm stuck on user authentication. After writing an AbstractGuardAuthenticator to handle authentication, I tested it with Postman. It logs in successfully and shows me the proper message, but when I try to access a secured route on the same tab or a different one while sending the same content (email and password), it throws this exception:

> Access denied, the user is not fully authenticated; redirecting to authentication entry point. exception="[object] (Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException(code: 403): Access Denied. at ...

Here is my code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Security;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Guard\AbstractGuardAuthenticator;

class LoginAuthenticator extends AbstractGuardAuthenticator
{
    private $passwordEncoder;

    public function __construct(UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder)
    {
        $this->passwordEncoder = $passwordEncoder;
    }

    public function supports(Request $request)
    {
        return 'api_login' === $request->get("_route")
            && $request->isMethod("POST");
    }

    public function getCredentials(Request $request)
    {
        $content = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
        return [
            'email' => $content["email"],
            'password' => $content["password"]
        ];
    }

    public function getUser($credentials, UserProviderInterface $userProvider)
    {
        return $userProvider->loadUserByUsername($credentials["email"]);
    }

    public function checkCredentials($credentials, UserInterface $user)
    {
        return $this->passwordEncoder->isPasswordValid($user, $credentials["password"]);
    }

    public function onAuthenticationFailure(Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception)
    {
        return new JsonResponse([
            "error" => $exception->getMessageKey()
        ], 400);
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, $providerKey)
    {
        return new JsonResponse([
            "status" => "success"
        ]);
    }

    public function start(Request $request, AuthenticationException $authException = null)
    {
        return new JsonResponse([
            'error' => 'Access Denied'
        ]);
    }

    public function supportsRememberMe()
    {
        // todo
        return false;
    }
}
```

Excerpt from the controller class:

```
   //Controller code

   /**
     * @Route("/profile", name="api_profile")
     */
    public function profile()
    {
        return $this->json([
            'user' => $this->getUser()
        ],
            200,
            [],
            [
                'groups' => ['visible']
            ]
        );
    }
```

And security.yaml:

```
    security:
      encoders:
        App\Entity\User:
          algorithm: auto

      # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
      providers:
        # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
        app_user_provider:
          entity:
            class: App\Entity\User
    security:
  encoders:
    App\Entity\User:
      algorithm: auto

  # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
  providers:
    # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
    app_user_provider:
      entity:
        class: App\Entity\User
        property: email
  firewalls:
    dev:
      pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
      security: false
    main:
      anonymous: true
      guard:
        authenticators:
          - App\Security\LoginAuthenticator
      logout:
        path: api_logout

      # activate different ways to authenticate
      # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#firewalls-authentication

      # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/impersonating_user.html
      # switch_user: true

  # Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
  # Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
  access_control:
    - { path: ^/user/official/register, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/state, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/profile, roles: ROLE_USER }
    # - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
    # - { path: ^/profile, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You're not authenticated anymore on other tabs, most likely because you're not sending the authentication cookie to your server. When you authenticate from your login endpoint, you get a cookie named **PHPSESSID**. If your credentials are correct, sending over this cookie in the header of your request will keep you logged in until the cookie expires.

First authenticate yourself with Postman or your web browser, then retrieve the generated PHPSESSID cookie and include it in all your futures Postman requests to stay authenticated.

Comment: Thank you. Thing is, I don't receive any cookies. I tried running the request on Chrome and Firefox and I didn't see any session cookies or any cookies at all. Out of frustration, I decided to make my backend stateless and authenticate via a JWT cookie, since I could stay authenticated per request. When I tried to set a cookie in the onAuthenticationSuccess method, I couldn't see the cookies I set in either Firefox or Chrome. When I ran the same code with a normal PHP script it worked, I just blatantly gave up on Symfony and am currently learning Laravel to use it on my Backend instead.